# SQL Server problem with restoring big databases

Tags: sql-server, database, sql

I often need to to backup and restore database(SQL Server 2000/2005). Now if database is of size > 1 GB restoration process is real time consuming.

Is there any way using which i can truncate the logs or reduce the database size?
Thanks all,

Comment: For the record, 1gb is a pretty small database.

Comment: define 'real time consuming'  30 seconds? 1 minute? 10 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to speed up your backup and restore process you may want to consider using third party backup technology such as.

[Quest Litespeed](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/)

On a side note, modyfying the size of your Transaction Log will not influence the volume of data that is being backed up/restored.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by "time-consuming"?

Restoring a 10 GB database should only take a couple of minutes. So no big deal at all. If you need to do this on a regular basis, create a job for that and schedule it to run before you get into the office.

Any action would have to take place before you backup the database, but I wouldn't recommend shrinking the files if you are going to restore the database on a production system.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you using [instant file initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935.aspx)?
- Is 1 GB backup size, MDF size or LDF size?

1 GB is quite small, really...